# Access BindingResult of Spring WebDataBinder without putting in the argument list

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use Spring validation with a controller interface generated by swagger-codegen. The swagger code generation supplies an abstract class for a controller. Our controller implements the codegen class and provides the actual logic. I would like to access the BindingResult in my controller methods, but swagger-codegen does not generate that parameter in its interface. Is there any way to get ahold of the BindingResults object other than specifying it as a parameter?

To make this more concrete, the codegen makes the endpoint like this (noisy code removed):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/repository/v1/datasets",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "application/json" },
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default ResponseEntity<JobModel> createDataset(@Valid @RequestBody DatasetRequestModel dataset) {
...
}
```

We implement a controller with the usual binder setup like:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(requestValidator)
}
```

but within the endpoint, we have no way to get the BindingResult since it has to match the signature of the codegen entry:

```
public ResponseEntity<StudySummaryModel> createStudy(@Valid @RequestBody StudyRequestModel studyRequest) {
...
}
```

I think the most straightforward solution may be to skip using WebDataBinder. Instead, I can have each controller endpoint call validators directly.

Answer (score 1):

I found another approach besides hand coding the validation; using an @ControllerAdvice class that extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

There is a nice example here: [Spring Validation Example](http://www.bbenson.co/post/spring-validations-with-examples/)

Here is my code based on that example that formats the error:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiValidationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        WebRequest request
    ) {
        BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();

        List<String> errorDetails = bindingResult
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(err -> err.getCode() + " error on '" + err.getObjectName() + "': " + err.getDefaultMessage())
            .collect(toList());

        ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel()
            .message("Validation errors - see error details")
            .errorDetail(errorDetails);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorModel, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and overriding the default implementation we can always register a custom exception handler which will override the default implementation

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, })
public ResponseEntity<GatewayException> requestValidationFailedHandler(
    final MethodArgumentNotValidException methodArgumentNotValidException) {
    log.error("exception: ", methodArgumentNotValidException);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).